# Efficient way of converting String column to Date in Pandas (in Python), but without Timestamp

Tags: string, pandas, date, type-conversion, timestamp

I am having a DataFrame which contains two String columns `df['month']` and `df['year']`. I want to create a new column `df['date']` by combining `month` and the `year` column. I have done that successfully using the structure below -

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime((df['month']+df['year']),format='%m%Y')
```

where by for `df['month'] = '08' and df['year']='1968'`

```
we get df['date']=1968-08-01
```

*This is exactly what I wanted.*

**Problem at hand:** My DataFrame has more than 200,000 rows and I notice that sometimes, in addition, I also get Timestamp like the one below for a few rows and I want to avoid that -

```
1972-03-01 00:00:00
```

I solved this issue by using the `.dt` acessor, which can be used to manipulate the Series, whereby I explicitly extracted only the date using the code below-

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime((df['month']+df['year']),format='%m%Y') #Line 1
df['date']=df['date']=.dt.date               #Line 2
```

The problem was solved, just that the *Line 2* took **5 times** more time than *Line 1*.

**Question:** Is there any way where I could tweak Line 1 into giving just the dates and not the Timestamp? I am sure this simple problem cannot have such an inefficient solution. Can I solve this issue in a more time and resource efficient manner?

Comment: In my opinion it is slow, because native pandas format is datetime64, no python date. I try `(df['month']+df['year']).apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%Y').date())`, but it is slowier :(

Comment: Yes, _lambda_ solutions are usually a tad slower and I can understand that this one is slower as well. I was comparing the speed of SAS with Pandas and unfortunately Pandas is slower in many cases. Or may be I am applying it in a wrong manner. Thanks _jezreal_, as always, for your inputs. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Hmmm, it is interesting. SAS is faster? How many times?

Comment: For this particular dataset where I am having some 5 Million rows, and I do multiple operations like sorting, changing the case from mixed to lower cases etc etc, in all it took me **42 seconds** in SAS and in Pandas in Python it took me **264** seconds. _6 times more._

Comment: Thank you. It is really slow.

Comment: I mean even changing the case from mixed to lowercase with `df['name']=df['name'].str.lower()` itself takes 4-5 seconds, which ultimately raises the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151264/discussion-between-oliver-s-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIk we don't have `date` dtype n Pandas, we only have `datetime`, so we will always have a time part.

Even though Pandas shows: `1968-08-01`, it has a time part: `00:00:00`.

Demo:

```
In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(['1968-08-01', '2017-08-01']), columns=['Date'])

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
        Date
0 1968-08-01
1 2017-08-01

In [34]: df['Date'].dt.time
Out[34]:
0    00:00:00
1    00:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

And if you want to have a **string** representation, there is a faster way:

```
df['date'] = df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['month'].astype(str) + '-01'
```

**UPDATE:** be aware that `.dt.date` will give you a **string** representation:

```
In [53]: df.dtypes
Out[53]:
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [54]: df['new'] = df['Date'].dt.date

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
        Date         new
0 1968-08-01  1968-08-01
1 2017-08-01  2017-08-01

In [56]: df.dtypes
Out[56]:
Date    datetime64[ns]
new             object   # <--- NOTE !!!
dtype: object
```

Comment: Well, I did not want string representation. It would have been straight forward then :) That said, if the time part is hidden, then why it sometimes shows up and other times it doesn't?

Comment: @OliverS, please be aware that `df['date'].dt.date` will give you a __string__ representation. See "UPDATE" for details

Comment: You are right MaxU. I was not aware of that. Thank you so much for bringing it out to notice. This renders the very idea of transforming the _Datetime_ to mere _Date_ useless, because if the idea is to convert to String, then why not simply concatenate, rather than following this long procedure for nothing. Thank you so much for your inputs. Much appreciated.

Comment: MaxU, I think I got the answer to the original question which motivated this question here. You solved that original question for me, needless to say! But, if I mark this question as answered then it gives the wrong impression that there exists an efficient method to extract dates. So, I would shy from marking it answered. Hope its ok MaxU.

Comment: @OliverS, sure :)